# Hiding and showing DIV with jQuery without using display:none

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the standard:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#toggleme').click(function(){
     $('div.#showhide').toggle();
   });
 $('#closer').click(function(){
     $('div.#showhide').toggle();
   });
 });
```

To show and hide a div, but when the site is set to `display:none;` the div disapears and all of my content moves up the page.

Is there a different way of showing/hiding the div, or should I wrap each div in a parent div with a fixed width/height?

Comment: one problem is ur use of `.#`, do you want an id or a class?

Comment: I thought the . was a separator character, can I just use #?

Comment: you can just use `#` and the elements ID to get first element with that ID. Using `.` will grab EVERY element with that class name. Examples: `$("#eleID")` will grab the 1st element with an id set to `eleID`, whereas; `$(".eleClass")` will grab **every** element that has the class `eleClass`

Comment: @williamsongibson - dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if it works for you..

Answer (score 2):

CSS attribute `visibility: hidden;` is what you want, it will hide it like display block but the space will still be there so no content moves.

Comment: I don't believe any version of IE supports this. Prob not the best cross-browser approach.

Comment: I am not sure about IE5.5, but i know that IE6 and up support visibility: hidden;

A neat way would be to set the opacity: 0; and having a transition on the element. For IE you would need a workaround, then.

Comment: No one supports less than IE7, so that point is mute, but not everyone upgrades there FF, and the Operas, and Even Safari, and all three of those have had issues with "visibility"

Answer (score 1):

make use of `.show()` and `hide()` method for that

[.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) - Display the matched elements.

[.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) - Hide the matched elements.

**or also try out**

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) - Display or hide the matched elements

Comment: toggle() does that under the surface. It won't resolve his issue of content moving.

Answer (score 0):

Set visibility to hidden like this:

```
$('div.#showhide').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Show it again like this:

```
$('div.#showhide').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Comment: This is not cross-compat (on most used versions today).

Comment: I tested in IE 7/8/9, Firefox and Chrome and it works in all. What browser does this not work in?

Comment: There are previous versions of FF, from just this past summer, it doesnt work correctly in, especially if inside a div with fixed or absolute position. I had that trouble just a few months ago. Recent updates have fixed the problem, but as aforementioned, some people don't update there firefox but maybe once a year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.show()`and `jQuery.hide()` methods for showing and hiding the elements respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#toggleme').toggle(function(){
        $('.showhide').animate({ "height", "0px" });
    },
    function(){
        $('.showhide').animate({ "height", "SomeBaseHeightpx" });
    });

    $('#closer').toggle(function(){
        $('.showhide').animate({ "height", "0px" });
    },
    function(){
        $('.showhide').animate({ "height", "SomeBaseHeightpx" });
    });

});
```

Play with it some and adjust it to your HTML, but that should do exactly what you want.

See more at [**jQuery .animate()**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) && [**jQuery .toggle() [event]**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)